# If $S^T = -S$ show that $I-S$ is nonsingular and that $(I-S)^{-1}(I+S)$ is orthogonal.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $S$ be an $n\times n$ matrix with $S^T = -S$. Show that $I-S$ is nonsingular and that $(I-S)^{-1}(I+S)$ is orthogonal (the question can be found [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jTi3W.png)).

$\mathbf{Hint}:$ First show that $(I-S)^{T}(I-S)$ is nonsingular. Then show and use the fact that

$$(I+S)(I-S) = (I-S)(I+S)$$

Have no idea even with the hint!

Comment: See [this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for how to write math formulas in questions (and answers) on this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First part: note that
$$
(I-S)^T(I-S) = I - S-S^T + S^TS = I+S^TS
$$
Now, we need to show that $I + S^TS$ is invertible.  There are a few options here: I'd say that you should either use positive definiteness or SVD.

Once you show that $(I+S)(I-S) = (I-S)(I+S)$, we have
$$
[(I-S)^{-1}(I+S)][(I-S)^{-1}(I+S)]^T = \\
(I - S)^{-1}(I+S)(I+S)^T[(I - S)^{-1}]^T = \\
(I - S)^{-1}(I+S)(I-S)[(I - S)^{-1}]^T = \\
(I - S)^{-1}(I-S)(I+S)[(I - S)^{-1}]^T = \\
\Big[(I - S)^{-1}(I-S)\Big] \Big[(I-S)^T[(I - S)^{T}]^{-1}\Big]
$$

Answer (score 1):

Use the hint and the relation $S^T=-S$ to get
$$(I-S)^T(I-S) = I^TI - I^TS-S^TI+S^TS = I+S^TS.$$
Now you need to show that $I+S^TS$ is nonsingular. One approach is to prove that $x^T(I+S^TS)x > 0$ for any $x\neq 0$.

Now use the result from your previous question to conclude $I-S$ is nonsingular.

For the last part, simplify $[(I-S)^{-1}(I+S)]^T(I-S)^{-1}(I+S)$ as much as you can using $S^T=-S$, then use the hint.

Comment: are the $x$'s in $R^n$ or $C^n?$ i mean what is the inner product?

Comment: @abel I'm assuming everything in sight is real. (Otherwise the problem statement isn't true.)

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Work with complex matrices. $S+S^*=0$  means $S = i H$ where $H$ is hermitian. Write $H = \tan \frac{T}{2}$ with $T$ hermitian and $\sigma(T) \subset (-\pi,\pi)$. Then we have 
$$\frac{1+S}{1-S}= \frac{1 + i \tan \frac{T}{2}}{1 - i \tan \frac{T}{2}}= \exp(i T)$$

is a unitary matrix.

Comment: Cute!  Classical!  Professional!  Von-Neumannesque!  Hence, ***Pluuuus Wunnnn!***

Comment: Neat. How can you see that $\tan$ is surjective from Hermitian matrices to Hermitian matrices?

Comment: @Robert Lewis: Thank you!

Comment: @user7530: Thanks. OK, diagonalize the Hermitian by a unitary,  reduce to the $1$-dim case, and now  $\tan\colon (- \pi/2, \pi/2) \to \mathbb{R}$ is surjective.

Comment: You are very welcome and deserving, my friend!

Answer (score 1):

First, note that

$(I - S)^T(I - S) = (I - S^T)(I - S)$
$= I - (S + S^T) + S^TS = I + S^TS \tag{1}$

since

$S + S^T = S - S = 0. \tag{2}$

Next, realize and/or recall that $I + S^TS$ is *always* nonsingular, for *any* real matrix $S$; this follows from the fact that, for any vector $v \ne 0$,

$\langle v, (I + S^TS)v \rangle = \langle v, v \rangle + \langle v, S^TSv \rangle$
$= \langle v, v \rangle + \langle Sv, Sv \rangle \ge \langle v, v \rangle > 0, \tag{3}$

by virtue of the facts that $\langle Sv, Sv \rangle \ge 0$ and $\langle v, v \rangle > 0$ for all $v \ne 0$.  Now (3) implies that

$(I + S^TS)v \ne 0 \tag{4}$

for all non-zero $v$; hence, $I + S^TS$ is nonsingular.  This in turn implies both $I - S$ and $I - S^T = I + S$ are nonsingular, since their product is the invertable matrix $I + S^TS$.  So that's done.

As for $(I - S)^{-1}(I + S)$, recall that for any invertable matrix $R$ we have

$(R^{-1})^T = (R^T)^{-1} \tag{5}$

which may be seen as follows:  we have

$RR^{-1} = I, \tag{6}$

and transposing we obtain

$(R^{-1})^TR^T = I \tag{7}$

as well; it is easily seen that (7) implies (5).  We thus have

$((I - S)^{-1})^T = (I - S^T)^{-1} = (I + S)^{-1}, \tag{8}$

whence

$(I - S)^{-1}(I + S)((I - S)^{-1}(I + S))^T$
$= (I - S)^{-1}(I + S)(I + S)^T((I - S)^{-1})^T = (I - S)^{-1}(I + S)(I - S)(I + S)^{-1}$
$= (I -S)^{-1}(I - S)(I + S)(I + S)^{-1} = I, \tag{9}$

as was to be shown.